# Keep getting errorcode in JCreator trying to put a JPanel in a JFrame

Tags: path, jframe, jpanel, jcreator

Hello my problem is that I want to get a JPanel into a JFrame with JCreator. Keep getting the same errorcode.

I'm already busy for three days with this problem and I can't get further with the course I'm following if I don't solve this problem.

The code below is what I try to compile:

import javax.swing.*;

public class Vb0202 extends JFrame 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    JFrame frame = new Vb0202();
    frame.setSize( 400, 200 );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setTitle( "Voorbeeld 0202" );
    JPanel paneel = new Paneel();
    frame.setContentPane( paneel );
    frame.setVisible( true );

}
```

}
public class Paneel extends JPanel 
{

```
private JButton knop;
private JTextField tekstvak;

public Paneel() 
{

    knop = new JButton( "Klik" );
    tekstveld = new JTextField( 10 );
    add( knop );
    add( tekstvak );
}
```

}

When I compile this code I get this error in my Build Output:

javac: file not found: src_vb0202.txt (Het systeem kan het opgegeven pad niet vinden)

And in my General Output I get this error:

Error: Could not find or load main class Vb0202.

Comment: please post the FULL error code in english, it would help a lot